# redirecting a page and displaying a message through javascript

Tags: node.js, alert

I have an HTML page which provides input fields for email ID and password, I use these values to connect with my backend SQL server through node js express application .

I have an app.post() method to connect with SQL.

```
app.post('/user', function (req, res, body) {
uid = req.body.user1;
pwd = req.body.user2;

    config = 'Server={ip of server};Database=Dbname;Uid=domain\\user' + uid + ';Pwd=' + pwd;

    var dbConn = new sql.Connection(config);
    dbConn.connect().then(function () {                                         //using promises instead of callbacks(onceconnect() is done), then go to then()

        var request = new sql.Request(dbConn);
         console.log('DONE');
    res.status(500).json({ status: 'done' })

    }).catch(function (err) {

        console.log("INVALID");
    res.status(500).json({ status: 'invalid' })
});
```

What I want to achieve is -

1. If the credentials are valid, displaying an alert 'DONE' at client side.
2. If the credentials are invalid, displaying an alert 'INVALID' at client side.

Currently, if everything is valid, there is DONE at /user.
If the ID and Password do not match, there is INVALID at /user.

My client side code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

 <body>

<form id ="target" action="/user" method="post"> 
    UserID : <input id="uid" type="text" name="user1" />                        <!text fields for date input>
    Password  : <input id="pwd" type="password" name="user2" />

    <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="LOGIN"/>       <!--<!submit button>-->
    <input id="Button" type="button" value="show graphs" onclick="btntest_onclick()" /> 
</form>

$.post("/user", function (data) {
    $("#target").html(data)
    alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
});

<script type="text/javascript">
    function btntest_onclick() {

    setTimeout(function () {

       window.location.href = "/../";
    },500);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am unable to use $.post() on client to retrieve data back from user- gives 500 error.
How do I proceed? Please help me.

Comment: First you are using setTimeoout , it has two parameters, first a callback second time parameter i dont see any time parameter.

Second thing you are trying to send response when you are getting any error. But if the username and password are invalid are sure you will get an error or something else in response from the database

Comment: Okay, I have to add some time parameter. But even without that, The error I get from the database is being displayed on the console when i write console.log(), but I want it on an alert

Comment: so you send that error in response and try to handle that at client side . alert is webapi will not work in nodejs

Comment: Can you show your client side code?

Comment: I have edited the question to include the client side code

Comment: You have to include jquery inside your client side code if you want to have a communication between nodejs and client side , so that you can make ajax call on click of the login button and get the response from the server , on that basis you can decide either you have to redirect the page or stay on the same page and show the alert.

Also this approach is right when you dont care about the response from the server and can move on . So include jquery and make a ajax call

Comment: hi, I was trying to solve as you had said and just realised that I have a really big trouble to solve before I can do that. I have simplified that and edited the question. Please let me know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve this by using the jquery ajax callback that returns back data to the client.

```
$("#target").submit(function (event) {

    var formData = {
        'uid': $('input[name=uid]').val(),
        'pwd': $('input[name=pwd]').val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
        url: '/user', // the url where we want to POST
        data: formData, // our data object
        dataType: 'json', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
        encode: true
    })
     .error(function (data) {

         // log data to the console so we can see
         alert(data.responseText);
     })
    .done(function (data) {

        // log data to the console so we can see
        console.log(data);

        // here we will handle errors and validation messages
    });
    event.preventDefault();

});
```

Comment: Yeah ... that what i told you ... earlier now check the data in the done function and and take decision on the basis of the response whether to stay on the same page and show the alert or redirect the page